# Ruby capitalize first character with spaces

Tags: ruby

Some rules: must use capitalization (not upcase or any other expression)

Stuck on the following:

```
string = <<-HERE
              i love tacos.  I hear
   they are delicious and nutritious

HERE
```

I need to capitalize the first word of each line with the whitespace and am having trouble figuring out how to get it done:

The output needs to look as follows:

```
              I love tacos.  I hear
   They are delicious and nutritious
```

Any guidance or help will be greatly appreciated.  I'll even take a point in the right direction rather than an answer!

Comment: What do you mean by "capitalize with the whitespace"?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner that does what you asked for:

`string.gsub(/^\s*\w/) {|match| match.upcase }`

I know you said "no upcase", but in this context, it's only upcasing the first letter. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

And to address your comment on the other answer, you can always use `gsub!` to mutate the string in place without creating a copy.

Comment: Drat! You beat me to it while I refreshed :D

Answer (score 3):

```
string.gsub!(/^\s*\w/){|match| match.upcase}
```

this will do what you want without creating new string.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
string = <<-HERE
              i love tacos.  I hear
   they are delicious and nutritious

HERE

string.gsub!(/(^\s*)(\w)/) do |match|
  $1 << $2.capitalize
end
```

What this attempts to do is split the string on newlines, search for the first letter, capitalize it and rejoin the fragments.

This will produce:

```
>           I love tacos.  I hear
   They are delicious and nutritious
```

Comment: It does work, but my question is: Can this be done at all without defining a new string?  From my instructions:  You are working with the original, unmodified version of the_string.
Some lines have leading spaces, which you cannot delete.  Also, you are awesome!!

Comment: I was trying to stick to your 'no upcase' spec, but if you're open to using it, the other answers here are nice and compact :) If your question pertains to performance, you could also eval char by char.