# Ruby: Method within a class refuses to be modified over multiple lines

Tags: ruby, rspec, class-method

I am currently doing an rspec ruby tutorial. One of the problems requires me to write a book_title program that utilizes some of the capitalization rules in English. The tests are extremely long but to give you a few ideas of what it is asking for I've included the first last tests below:

```
require 'book'

describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end

   specify 'the first word' do
       @book.title = "the man in the iron mask"
       @book.title.should == "The Man in the Iron Mask"
     end
    end
  end
end
```

My code is:

```
class Book
    attr_accessor :title

    def initialize(title = nil)
        @title = title
    end

    def title=(book_title = nil)
        stop_words = ["and", "in", "the", "of", "a", "an"]
        @title = book_title.split(" ").each{ |word| 
            unless stop_words.include?(word)
                word.capitalize!
            end}.join(" ").capitalize
    end
end
```

This issue I am having is with the `def title=` method. `@title = book_title.split`(...etc) all in one line because when I try and split it up, many of my previous tests fail.

Example of some code I've tried:

```
    @title = book_title.split(" ").each do |word|  # attempting to add words to an array
        unless stop_words.include?(word)           # to capitalize each word
          word.capitalize!
        end
      end
        @title.join(" ")                               # Joining words into one string
        @title.capitalize                              # Capitalizing title's first word
    end                                                # to follow the last test
```

When I try this the tests fail (I am thinking it has to do with calling @title again when I try @title#join and @title#capitalize).

Some other thoughts: I was thinking about just setting the first part (the longest line ending in `word.capitalize! end end` to a different variable (maybe book_title or new_title) but I was wondering what the reason for even initializing or using @title would be in the first place.

Any input, as well as edits for cleaner code, would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The code breaks, or your tests fail?

Comment: tests fail after the inferno test

Comment: I'm not sure when you saying "code breaks". if you want the first letter capitalize by preserving the rest of capitalized characters, you just need to upcase the first char via regexp. see [Ruby capitalize first character with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471511/ruby-capitalize-first-character-with-spaces). Personally I would also suggest that using getter to do string tweak instead of setter.

Comment: @shawnzhu Sorry I edited my post. I don't mean to say that code breaks (as clarified in a comment to Zach Kemp). I meant to say many of the other tests fail (for reasons Zach explained in his answer). As for capitalizing the first letter, the page you linked is very helpful (thanks) but this problem also deals with some words that should not be capitalized. e.g. "war and peace" should turn into "War and Peace"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having in the second example is that `Array#each` returns the enumerable on which `.each` was called, so in this case you're getting the result from `book_title.split(" ")` (albeit modified by the block). You are assigning this result to the `@title` instance variable. Calling `join` on an array returns a string, but you're not doing anything with that string except allocating it. If you'd like to assign it to the title variable, you need to do `@title = @title.join(" ")`. Same with `capitalize`.

Comment: That really clarifies a ton for me, thank you. One last question I had was with the last test. The last test is asking for me to capitalize the first work. I've tried using `@title = @title.capitalize` as the last statement but it does nothing. It still says the test failed

Comment: A small point: _Array#each returns the enumerable on which .each was called_ ... not when a block is supplied (Did the op change the example?). And when a block is not supplied, each() returns an Enumerator, which is decidedly not the same thing as the enumerable on which each() was called. Try this: `arr = [1, 2, 3] puts arr.object_id x = [1, 2, 3].each puts x.object_id`. Enumerable is a module that classes include for the methods contained therein. Enumerator is a class, an instance of which is returned by each() when no block is supplied. ++ anyway